# The number of zeros in the expansion of $n!$ in base $12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, factorial

During an interview last year I was asked the following question:

> How many zeros appear at the end of $n!$ in base $12$, where $n$ is a positive integer?

I applied the known Legendre formula for $p=3$ and then for $p=2$ (in the last case followed by a division by $2$). Then I realised that I couldn't compare the two series produced.

It turned out that the interviewer was an applied mathematician and considered the two series to be "equal".

So the question remained unanswered:

> Which of the produced series is greater for each value of $n$?

Comment: Not sure I am following.  There are at least as many multiples of $2$ less than $n$ then there are of $3$ (clearly).  There are at least as multiples of $2^2$ less than $n$ then there are of $3^2$, and so on.

Comment: We are talking about base 12, not base 6.
We consider powers of 4 dividing n! and powers of 3 dividing n!.

Comment: (sorry, I pressed enter by mistake)
Therefore, we want to compare the greatest $s$ such that $4^s|n!$ and the greatest $t$ such that $3^t|n!$. For the first case, we apply the known formula for $p=2$, and then divide by $2$. You are just considering powers of $2$, not of $4$ (i.e. you forgot dividing by 2).
(We can see that if we drop the floor functions -integer parts- we end up with two identical series. That's where the difficulty is)
Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: No, you were perfectly clear.  For whatever reason I just changed it to base $6$.  Interesting question...

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a nice problem, though a proper solution is pretty involved for a job interview.

Here's a compact way to repackage this: The largest power $k$ of a prime $p$ that divides $n!$ is the $p$-adic valuation $$v_p(n!) := \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor$$ of $n!$. Expanding this necessarily finite sum and [applying a little middle school algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#Proof) shows that we can rewrite this as $$v_p(n!) = \frac{n - S_p(n)}{p - 1},$$ where $S_p(n)$ is the sum of digits of $n$ in base $p$. (So, if one already has access to the base-$2$ and -$3$ representations of $n$, this computation is very fast.)

Now, the largest power of $3$ that divides $n$ is $$\boxed{v_3(n!) = \tfrac{1}{2}(n - S_3(n))} ,$$
and the largest power of $4$ that divides $n$ is $$\boxed{\left\lfloor \tfrac{1}{2} v_2(n!)\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \tfrac{1}{2} (n - S_2(n))\right\rfloor}$$ (note that $S_2(n)$ is just the number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$). Thus, the largest power of $12$ that divides $n!$ (and therefore the number of $0$'s at the end of the base-$12$ representation of $n!$) is
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{Z_{12}(n) := \min \left\{\tfrac{1}{2}(n - S_3(n)), \tfrac{1}{2} (n - S_2(n))\right\}}} .$$

If $n$ is a power $2^a$ of $2$, $a \geq 3$, then $S_2(n) = 1$, and so $$\left\lfloor \tfrac{1}{2} (n - S_2(n))\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \tfrac{1}{2} (n - 1)\right\rfloor = \tfrac{1}{2} n - 1 > \left\lfloor \tfrac{1}{2} (n - S_3(n))\right\rfloor ,$$ that is, the number of factors of $3$ in $n!$ is smaller than the number of factors of $4$. On the other hand, if $n$ is a power of $3$, the reverse is true, so it is not the case that one factor or the other always dominates for sufficiently large $n$.

**Remark** This last fact is not equivalent to saying that each dominates the other with equal probability; it could be an interesting problem to compute, e.g., how often factors of $3$ dominate, asymptotically, i.e., the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\#\left\{\tfrac{1}{2}(n - S_3(n)) > \tfrac{1}{2} (n - S_2(n)) : 1 \leq n \leq N\right\}}{N} .$$

From the above analysis, we can see immediately how to choose bases that have this critical behavior wherein some powers of the prime factors of the base are on even footing; the next smallest after $12$ is $45 = 3^2 \cdot 5$. The smallest base in which three prime factors are on mutually equal footing is $2^6 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 7 = 12096$.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
By the way, it was a university interview (cambridge in particular), not a job interview.

To be honest, I already considered the cases of powers of $2$ and $3$ (probably during the actual interview).

I am more interested in a way to distinguish which of the two expressions is greater (separetly) for each positive integer $n$ in general- or at least for some more general cases. (Although other results e.g. concerning densities as your example, or bounds of the difference of the two expressions would also be interesting).

Comment: The answer tells you how to determine that efficiently for any given $n$: Just compute the quantities $\frac{1}{2}(n - S_3(n))$ and $\left\lfloor \tfrac{1}{2}(n - S_2(n))\right\rfloor$ and see which is larger.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my fault. I was not clear enough. Actually, in the way I asked my question, the "just compute the two series manually" method is also an answer -terms eventually become $0$. I was thinking about a simpler rule, not an algorithm (at least not of complexity great enough to bother calling the rule an algorithm). Even if it doesn't concern all the positive integers or if it is not completely accurate. Probably something using more advanced or at least not well-known results, e.g. some approximation formulas for $S_p(n)$. Of course there is no evidence of such rule but you never know.

Comment: Hm, it's not quite clear to me what exactly you're looking for, then. I doubt one can improve any on naive approximation formulas for $S_p(n)$---after all, its values are not at all stable under small variations in $n$ (consider the increment $1011\cdots 11$ to $1100\cdots 00$ for $p = 2$). Anyway, this method really is essentially equivalent to "compute the series manually", just repackaged in a compact, finite way. It really is an improvement if one has access to the base-$2$ and -$3$ representations of $n$, in which case the problem is just $O(\log_p n)$ additions and two divisions.